# Meaning of "pass on"

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

I found on the free dictionary By Farlex this definition: [Link](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+on)

- pass on : accept or approve someone or something

and they gave this example :

- The committee passed on the proposal, so work can now begin.

I always thought "pass on"  means to decline something

Is the definition given by Farlex correct?

Comment: This is an odd one. If you remove the *on* from the example, it reads perfectly and unambiguously. (There was a proposal, which was [passed/approved](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pass))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to that dictionary, yes, *pass on* can have directly contradictory meanings.

I don't believe I have ever met that usage, and I'm not sure I would have interpreted it as given.

I would also not expect *pass on* = decline for a committee, because to my ear that use is rather colloquial, and I would expect a more formal expression when talking about a committee.

I would probably interpret it as "To give, transmit, transfer, or deliver something", and understand that the committee had passed the proposal on to somebody else.

Comment: Is the usage given by the dictionary rare or is wrong?

Comment: I don't know. I've never seen it. I note that only one of the sources that that site references gives that meaning, but you'd have to check that source (McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs) for more information. Looking for "the committee passed on" in the largest corpora at english-corpora.org, I can find six examples of construction: in this sense. All are US source, four relate to sports, and two to government. And in every case, from the single line reported in the corpus, I don't know whether it means they approved or rejected.

Comment: Correction - one of the six (relating to government) is from Pakistan. But I have looked at the sources: there is one I cannot see because of GDPR rules. But the other five all have the sense of "rejected". So from my (very brief) search, I cannot confirm that the phrase "the committee passed on" has ever been used to mean "the committee approved".

Comment: I will therefore qualify my ealier statement that "I don't know whether it means they approved or rejected". If it hadn't been for this question, and the source you mentioned, it would never have occurred to me that they meant anything other than "rejected" .